# Getting list of files in directory with python

Tags: python, regex, system

I generally have a common task where I need to run a script on a data set composed of thousands of files (20,000 to 50,000). This list is usually dynamic so I've been trying to come up with a solution where my Python code will generate a list of all files I need.

My current solution is:

```
os.system("ls " + dir + " | grep -i "\.extension" > " + dir + "temp.text")
with open(dir + "temp.txt", "rb") as fi:
    #parse
```

The problem is that this can be very slow when many files are present and many file types are present. Is there a smarter way to handle this?

Comment: Why on earth are you using `ls` instead of [`os.listdir()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.listdir)?

Comment: Storing 20,000 to 50,000 in a single directory is bound to be slow no matter what you do ...

Comment: I realize that, but there isn't a useful way to split them up into sub directories other than by file name.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're not using `os` here.

```
import os
filelist = os.listdir(dir)
for file in filelist:
    with open(os.path.join(dir, file), 'rb') as fi:
         #parse
```

Comment: This is certainly a more pythonic way of accomplishing the task, but it does not address the main issue raised in the question: speed.

Comment: @Lanaru, is there any indication that `os.listdir` will not work faster than `os.system`?

Comment: No clue. If you are submitting that your solution is faster than the original one, then please time them both and show us the results. That would make for a much better answer.